# Load several js function from the same jquery file unto several html pages at different intervals of my choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one main.js file with several functions (such as ajax calls and page-function based) that I need to load on different intervals and different pages. My problem is that `$(document).ready(function(){});` loads everything at once.

I know in jqm I can use `.on ('pageinit', "pagename", event(){});`

Is there something similar to jquery? I'd like to keep one .js file for all my js functions in  my web-app.

Thanks much.

Comment: Sure, use different selectors for elements, check the current URL, give the body or html tags a special class etc.

Comment: Hi adeneo, thanks for your answer. I have several ajax calls that belong to different pages. I'd like to call those only when those pages load (as well as other functions that are suppose to load on 'page-ready' - rather than 'trigger-events'.

Comment: `if (window.location.href == 'mysite/page2.php')`

Comment: `if ($("body").hasClass("xyz")) { ... }` or check the `id`, etc.

Comment: Thaks, that's nice! Up-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement this on your own. But you can for example set ids for your pages and use them as "function-selectors". Crapy example:

HTML

```
<body id="foo"></body>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    siteFunctions = {};

    siteFunctions.foo = function() {
        alert('bar');
    }

    var siteId = $('body').attr('id');
    if (typeof siteFunctions[siteId] == 'function') siteFunctions[siteId]();
}
```